# [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in markdown(' '). htmlentities problem? [marked.js]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, html-entities, laravel-6

I'm using [marked.js](https://marked.js.org/) to add git flavoured markdown to my Laravel app.

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($entries as $entry)
    <a href="/entry/{{$entry->id}}"><h3>{{ $entry->created_at->format('M d Y') }}</h3></a>
    <div v-html="markdown('{{ htmlentities($entry->content) }}')"> </div>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

**app.js**

```
const marked = require('marked');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    methods: {
        markdown(input){
            return marked(input, { sanitize: true })
        }
    }
});
```

When I run this and add words like "break", "for" or even just basic new paragraph (return), I get an error in the browser console and none of the content shows up.:

> app.js:41078 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>
> invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in
>
> ```
> markdown('smsa.mdsads
> ```
>
> hi')
>
> Raw expression: v-html="markdown('smsa.mdsads
>
> hi')"
>
> 63 |                   64 |
>   
>
> #### Nov 09 2019
>
>  65 |
>   
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 66 |      |   67 |  hi')">     | 
>   ^^^^^
>
> (found in )

**Note**

I'm pretty sure this isn't a marked.js problem since I'm using marked in my vue components on so JSON, and it works great. Example:

**RecordComponent.vue that works**

```
<div  v-for="(record, index) in records">

    <h4>Content</h4>
    <div v-if="record.content" v-html="markdown(record.content)"></div>
    <p v-else style="color: #d02105;">Please fill out later</p>

    <hr>

</div>
```